# Why are subviews not visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I created `FirstController` in storyboard, added it class also. I using segue(using buttons in storyboard) to show `FirstController`, but I can't see its subviews. I tried to look into debugger, but frame is fine and `.hidden` properties are set to NO, alpa 1. I even have IBAction, when i press place where should be my firstVCButton, but still no visible content.  (Content also visible in storyboard, but not when app running).

Comment: What views do you have, and what constraints have you added to them?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint on viewDidAppear and check out the [view debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) to see if they're where you expect them to be.

Comment: Reworded title to be question

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking isHidden and alpha, you should also check the subviews' frames as well the the frame of their superviews. The subviews could be off-screen or the superview could be too small to display the missing views.